# doReturn doesn't act as proxy but calls my method

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

I'm implementing some Unit testing in my app and I have a dependency that relies in the `Application` context. That dependency returns a list of `Item` but I want to mock that logic to return whatever I want.

I already know the difference between:

a) `when(foo.method1()).return(bar)`

b)  `doReturn(bar).when(foo).method1()`

**(b)** shouldn't invoke the method.

Now I have a method called in `ItemHelper.kt` :

```
fun retrieveItems(): MutableList<Item> {
    val boxStore = BoxStore.getInstance().getBoxFor(Item::class.java)
    return boxStore.all
}
```

and that `.getInstance()` relies on the `Application`.

Since I want to mock it, this is my test:

```
class ItemHelperTests {

    @JvmField
    @Rule
    var mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule()!!

    @Mock
    private lateinit var itemHelper: ItemHelper

    @Test
    fun itemsNumber_Test() {
        Mockito.doReturn(ArrayList<Item>()).`when`(itemHelper).retrieveItems()

        System.out.println("this line is unreachable")
    }
}
```

but that ends calling my code:

```
java.lang.Exception: Please init BoxStore.boxStore in the MainApplication

    at com.example.dependencies.coreData.BoxStore$Companion.throwBoxStoreNotInitialized(BoxStore.kt:33)
    at com.example.dependencies.coreData.BoxStore$Companion.getInstance(BoxStore.kt:26)
    at com.example.helpers.coreData.Item.ItemHelper.retrieveItems(ItemHelper.kt:20)
    at com.example.helpers.ItemHelperTests.itemsNumber_Test(ItemHelperTests.kt:27)
```

so that method is called, I just want to retrieve an empty `ArrayList()` when that method is called from JVM.

---

**EDIT**

When using `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)`

I get the same error, but I get one more line of Mockito error:

```
java.lang.Exception: Please init BoxStore.boxStore in the MainApplication

    at com.example.dependencies.coreData.BoxStore$Companion.throwBoxStoreNotInitialized(BoxStore.kt:33)
    at com.example.dependencies.coreData.BoxStore$Companion.getInstance(BoxStore.kt:26)
    at com.example.helpers.coreData.Item.ItemHelper.retrieveItems(ItemHelper.kt:20)
    at com.example.helpers.ItemHelperTests.itemsNumber_Test(ItemHelperTests.kt:27)

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at com.example.helpers.ItemHelperTests.itemsNumber_Test(ItemHelperTests.kt:27)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, which is not supported
 3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed


    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1$1.testFinished(DefaultInternalRunner.java:69)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.SynchronizedRunListener.testFinished(SynchronizedRunListener.java:56)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$7.notifyListener(RunNotifier.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$SafeNotifier.run(RunNotifier.java:72)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier.fireTestFinished(RunNotifier.java:187)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.EachTestNotifier.fireTestFinished(EachTestNotifier.java:38)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:78)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:84)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:161)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Kotlin every class and method is closed.

I had to define `open` before `retrieveItems()`, remaining:

```
open fun retrieveItems(): MutableList<Item> {
    val boxStore = BoxStore.getInstance().getBoxFor(Item::class.java)
    return boxStore.all
}
```